# Connect Four game

Tags: c, console, connect-four

I wrote this a couple months ago and just wanted to get some feedback on it. In the `printBoard()` function, you see I commented out the system function. I've read this is considered bad practice.  Does anyone know of any alternative to clearing the terminal window?  I thought it'd be a nice touch to clear the window instead of just having the updated board appear below the previous.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define BOARD_ROWS 6
#define BOARD_COLS 7

void printBoard(char *board);
int takeTurn(char *board, int player, const char*);
int checkWin(char *board);
int checkFour(char *board, int, int, int, int);
int horizontalCheck(char *board);
int verticalCheck(char *board);
int diagonalCheck(char *board);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   const char *PIECES = "XO";
   char board[BOARD_ROWS * BOARD_COLS];
   memset(board, ' ', BOARD_ROWS * BOARD_COLS);

   int turn, done = 0;

   for(turn = 0; turn < BOARD_ROWS * BOARD_COLS && !done; turn++){
      printBoard(board);   
      while(!takeTurn(board, turn % 2, PIECES)){
         printBoard(board);   
         puts("**Column full!**\n");
      }
      done = checkWin(board);
   } 
   printBoard(board);

   if(turn == BOARD_ROWS * BOARD_COLS && !done){
      puts("It's a tie!");
   } else {
      turn--;
      printf("Player %d (%c) wins!\n", turn % 2 + 1, PIECES[turn % 2]);
   }

   return 0;

}
void printBoard(char *board){
   int row, col;

   //system("clear");
   puts("\n    ****Connect Four****\n");
   for(row = 0; row < BOARD_ROWS; row++){
      for(col = 0; col < BOARD_COLS; col++){
         printf("| %c ",  board[BOARD_COLS * row + col]);
      }
      puts("|");
      puts("-----------------------------");

   }
   puts("  1   2   3   4   5   6   7\n");

}
int takeTurn(char *board, int player, const char *PIECES){
   int row, col = 0;
   printf("Player %d (%c):\nEnter number coordinate: ", player + 1, PIECES[player]);

   while(1){ 
      if(1 != scanf("%d", &col) || col < 1 || col > 7 ){
         while(getchar() != '\n');
         puts("Number out of bounds! Try again.");
      } else { 
         break;
      }
   }
   col--;

   for(row = BOARD_ROWS - 1; row >= 0; row--){
      if(board[BOARD_COLS * row + col] == ' '){
         board[BOARD_COLS * row + col] = PIECES[player];
         return 1;
      }
   }
   return 0;

}
int checkWin(char *board){
    return (horizontalCheck(board) || verticalCheck(board) || diagonalCheck(board));

}
int checkFour(char *board, int a, int b, int c, int d){
    return (board[a] == board[b] && board[b] == board[c] && board[c] == board[d] && board[a] != ' ');

}
int horizontalCheck(char *board){
    int row, col, idx;
    const int WIDTH = 1;

    for(row = 0; row < BOARD_ROWS; row++){
       for(col = 0; col < BOARD_COLS - 3; col++){
          idx = BOARD_COLS * row + col;
          if(checkFour(board, idx, idx + WIDTH, idx + WIDTH * 2, idx + WIDTH * 3)){
             return 1;
          }
       }
    }
    return 0;

}
int verticalCheck(char *board){
    int row, col, idx;
    const int HEIGHT = 7;

    for(row = 0; row < BOARD_ROWS - 3; row++){
       for(col = 0; col < BOARD_COLS; col++){
          idx = BOARD_COLS * row + col;
          if(checkFour(board, idx, idx + HEIGHT, idx + HEIGHT * 2, idx + HEIGHT * 3)){
              return 1;
          }
       }
    }
    return 0;

}
int diagonalCheck(char *board){
   int row, col, idx, count = 0;
   const int DIAG_RGT = 6, DIAG_LFT = 8;

   for(row = 0; row < BOARD_ROWS - 3; row++){
      for(col = 0; col < BOARD_COLS; col++){
         idx = BOARD_COLS * row + col;
         if(count <= 3 && checkFour(board, idx, idx + DIAG_LFT, idx + DIAG_LFT * 2, idx + DIAG_LFT * 3) || count >= 3 && checkFour(board, idx, idx + DIAG_RGT, idx + DIAG_RGT * 2, idx + DIAG_RGT * 3)){
            return 1;
         }
         count++;
      }
      count = 0;
   }
   return 0;

}
```

Comment: To clear the screen in a Linux terminal, use the [ncurses library](http://linux.die.net/man/3/curs_clear).  Under windows, see [Microsoft KB 92261](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/99261).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some comments, in no particular order:

**1:** For applications like this, I think it is perfectly legitimate to use `system()`. It's not exactly elegant, but in this particular case I think it's fine. You could do:

```
void clearScreen() {
#ifdef WIN32
    system("cls");
#else
    system("clear");
#endif // WIN32
}
```

**2:** Consider using the [C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) or [C11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) standards. They allow a couple of things that make the code easier to read and maintain. For example, substitute your `#define`s with `const int BOARD_ROWS = 6`. This helps debugging (because you see `BOARD_ROWS` and not `6` in the compiler and debugger output), adds scope to the variables and generally avoids most of the problems with `#define`s.

C99 and C11 don't require that variable definitions appear at the beginning of their scope. This means you can keep variables closer to their relevant context. The most useful example for this is `for` loops. In C99 and C11, you can write

```
 for (int row = 0; row < BOARD_ROWS; ++row)
```

C99 also introduced a `bool` type (which is actually just a typedef for `int`). This makes the code more readable. Usage example: `bool done = false; while (!done) { ... done = true; }`. The bool type is of course available in C11 as well.

**3:** What is the value of `row` after `int row, col = 0;`? It's unspecified, so `row` can have any value. If you mean to initialize both variables, which you should, you need to write `int row = 0, col = 0;`.

(There's a similar gotcha in C. What's the type of p2 in this snippet: `int *p1, p2;`? It's a plain `int`, only `p1` is an `int*`. To make both variables pointers, write `int *p1, *p2`.)

**4:** Consider using `printf` consistently instead of `puts`.

**5:** Consider preferring pre-increment operators. `row++` means "increment row, then return a copy of what it looked like before incrementing". `++row` means "increment row", which is what you mean. It's not a big difference in this case, and the compiler can optimize away the extra copy, but I like the habit of writing exactly what you mean. If you ever start writing C++-code with user-defined increment operators, this can actually be important.

**6:** Try to always initialize your variables, rather than set their value at a later time. It's faster, cleaner and safer. Note that static and global variables are guaranteed to be zero-initialized when the program starts, but it doesn't hurt to be explicit.

**7:** Full variable names are easier to read, and there's no good reason not to type them out. Prefer `index` over `idx`, `DIAGONAL_RIGHT` over `DIAG_RGT` and so on.

**8:** Personally, I prefer `for (;;)` over `while (1)`. The former is commonly read out loud as "forever".

**9:** Consider adding documentation and comments to your code. For example Doxygen comments before each function.

**10:** Code that is not self-explanatory should be factored out into separate functions with meaningful names. Consider your `while(getchar() != '\n');`. Putting this into a function called either `flushInputBuffer()` or `waitForEnter()` conveys intent and what is going on much better than the original code.

**11:** Consider changing your whitespace to increase readability. Instead of
        return 0;

```
    }
    int diagonalCheck(char *board){
```

write

```
    return 0;
    }

    int diagonalCheck(char *board) {
```

to emphasize that the closing bracket belongs to the topmost function, not the bottom one. Also consider whitespace before brackets, for example. This is a matter of preference, the most important thing is that you're consistent and that the code is readable.

**12:** Break up long lines into more, shorter lines. This is a tremendous help for readability, and especially helps when doing source control merges, debugging in a debugger and other cases where your window width is limited. It's common to limit lines to 80-100 characters.

**13:** Consider sorting `#include`s in alphabetical order.

**14:** Consider using unit tests.

**15:** There are several things you are doing that are *good*. For example using symbolic rather than literal constants, i.e. `const int DIAG_RGT = 6, DIAG_LFT = 8;`. Your program is also fairly well divided into functions, and most variable names are reasonably named. Keep doing these things.

Comment: Thanks! I don't really have a very profound reason, it's just that I think the "print" makes `printf` clearer than `puts`. I like the principle of least astonishment, and my impression is that `printf` is more common. I base that only on code I've read and not on any research, so I may well be biased.

Comment: Thanks for the review. Regarding `puts`, my friend who's a software developer said to use it if you're just printing a string because it doesn't have to analyze the string format that `printf` does. As far as I know, it probably isn't gonna make much difference for speed, other than its 2 letters shorter to type. I've just always had the habit of doing that.

Comment: It's very typical of C-programmers to think like that, but I recommend preferring readability over performance except in the critical path :) By the way, if you feel that the answer is satisfactory, feel free to click *accept answer*. If you like another answer better, accept it instead.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some extra points not covered by the excellent review from @Lstor

You can avoid the need for prototypes by putting `main` at the end.  This
might seem odd but it is quite common practice.  Also, your functions could
all be `static`, as they are used only in this file.  For single-file programs
this is of no significance, but for large programs it is best practice as it
avoids polluting the namespace and may make optimisation possible.

---

This:

```
char board[BOARD_ROWS * BOARD_COLS];
memset(board, ' ', BOARD_ROWS * BOARD_COLS);
```

is better written with `sizeof`

```
char board[BOARD_ROWS * BOARD_COLS];
memset(board, ' ', sizeof board);
```

This guarantees that the array is cleared even if you were to change the size of `board` and forgot to change the `memset` line.

---

As there are only two ways of leaving the for-loop in `main`, namely when
`(turn >= BOARD_ROWS * BOARD_COL)` and when `done` is set, this line following
the loop:

```
if(turn == BOARD_ROWS * BOARD_COLS && !done){
```

is the same as just testing `!done`

---

Your input loop in `takeTurn` is unusual. I would usually use `fgets` rather
than `scanf` (using `scanf` results in you having to purge the input on false data, as you discovered, because `scanf` doesn't remove the false data from the input stream. Also your loop doesn't check for the input stream being closed):

```
int col = 0;
char buf[10];
while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) != NULL) {
    col = (int) strtol(buf, 0, 0);
    if (col >= 1 && col <= 7 ) {
        break;
    }
    puts("Number out of bounds! Try again.");
}
if (col == 0) { // user entered ctrl-d to end input
    exit(1);
}
```

---

The fact that you **always** call `checkBoard` with the 4th and 5th parameters
multiplied by 2 and 3 respectively implies to me that the function might be
better doing the multiplications.

---

Your long expression:

```
if(count <= 3 &&
   checkFour(board, idx, idx + DIAG_LFT, idx + DIAG_LFT * 2, idx + DIAG_LFT * 3) ||
   count >= 3 &&
   checkFour(board, idx, idx + DIAG_RGT, idx + DIAG_RGT * 2, idx + DIAG_RGT * 3)){
   return 1;
}
```

needs some brackets.  The compiler gives me this warning:

```
 warning: '&&' within '||' [-Wlogical-op-parentheses]
```

Comment: +1. Many valid points that I had missed. Regarding using `sizeof` with `memset`: I wholly agree. When doing so, however, it is very important not to do it through a function. Arrays are demoted to pointers when passed to functions, and the size will in that case be the same as `sizeof(char*)`.